# Inappropriate value for "role":string required terraform12

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, infrastructure-as-code

I have written a terraform configuration file for a bastion entry point on an application.

```
    ami = var.ami
    ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized
    iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_instance_profile
    instance_type = var.instance_type
    key_name = "quadops"
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id
    user_data = var.user_data
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.name}"
        Business = "Infrastracture"
        app_name = "infra"
        app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
    volume_tags = {
        Name = "${var.name}"
        Business = "Infrastracture"
        app_name = "infra"
        app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
    name = "${var.name}-security-group"
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    ingress {
    from_port        = 22
    to_port          = 22
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
    egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.name}"
        Business = "Infrastracture"
        app_name = "infra"
        app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "iam_instance_profile" {
    name = "${var.name}-iam-instance-profile"
    role = aws_iam_role.iam_role 
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.name}"
        Business = "Infrastracture"
        app_name = "infra"
        app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role" {
    assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
    name = "${var.name}-iam-role"
    tags = {
      Name = "${var.name}-iam-role"
      Business = "Infrastracture"
      app_name = "infra"
      app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
}

resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
    vpc = true
    instance = aws_instance.instance.id
    tags = {
      Name = "${var.name}-eip"
      Business = "Infrastracture"
      app_name = "infra"
      app_env = "${var.env}"
    }
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
    zone_id = var.zone_id
    name = "bastion.${var.env}"
    type = "A"
    value = "aws_eip.eip.public_ip"
}
```

Upon running plan, i'm getting this error.

```
  on .terraform/modules/bastion/main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "iam_instance_profile":
  49:     role = aws_iam_role.iam_role 
    |----------------
    | aws_iam_role.iam_role is object with 15 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "role": string required.
```

I can't seem to get over this hurdle as I think i'm calling the resource correctly but terraform12 says that it requires a string am I passing the values incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the entire `aws_iam_role` object to the `role` argument which is causing the error. Instead, try passing the name of the role like so:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "iam_instance_profile" {
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_role.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out, but in my case I used .id instead of .name as reference attribute. Great help!